# How does 'whereis' find files so quickly?

Tags: shell, util-linux

I was recently trying to find a binary file with a certain name. I decided to use the `whereis` search utility (part of the util-linux package). This managed to find the file in half the time than trying to use the comparable `find` command.

I've also used the `locate` command which produces results in speeds similar to `whereis`.

How do these commands manage to find files so quickly in comparison to the `find` command?

Comment: `locate` reads from a database that is updated by a much slower, CPU-intensive search (`updatedb`), typically run as a cron job...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` does a blind walk of the entire filesystem looking for matches.  It takes so long because it's looking at every file in every directory and not stopping until it's covered the whole filesystem.

`locate` also covers the whole filesystem but it speeds things up by having a prebuilt database (updated with the `updatedb` command) that it uses to find matching files.

`whereis` and `which` also search through directories looking for files but they only search through a very specific subset of places in the filesystem (usually specified by environment variables like `$PATH` and `$MANPATH` as appropriate).  They also stop a the first occurrence leading to faster run times.

Comment: this answer assumes a GNU `find`. an AT&T `find` will default to searching an `slocate` database where one is available.

Comment: @mikeserv  I didn't know that.  Thanks!